# Client-side HTTPS mutual certificate example with o.js on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, odata

Can anyone show an example of using [o.js](https://github.com/janhommes/o.js) on node.js using an HTTPS connection while supplying certificates?

I currently have the following example using the node.js `https` module directly, but I'm looking to use `o.js` lib to avoid crafting the OData URLs manually:

```js
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const requestParams = {
    hostname: "<the hostname>",
    port: 44300,
    key: fs.readFileSync("path/to/client-key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("path/to/client-crt.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("path/to/ca-crt.pem"),
    rejectUnauthorized : false, // NOT FOR PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENTS
    path: "<the OData URL>",
    method: "<GET/POST/DELETE etc>"
};

const httpsReq = https.request(requestParams, httpsRes => {
    // Handle the response here
});

httpsReq.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As o.js accepts the fetch-options as a second parameter you might be able to add a agent to o.js config:

```
// Configure HTTPS agent with the necessary certificates
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  key: fs.readFileSync("path/to/client-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("path/to/client-crt.pem"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("path/to/ca-crt.pem"),
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // NOT FOR PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENTS
});

const oHandler = o('http://my-url', ({ agent: httpsAgent }) as any);
```

It needs casting, as I assume that it only knows about the fetch options for the browser (and `agent` seems to be a node.js only option).